# Drag-and-drop files to another folder on the Path Bar?

Tags: mac, finder, file-transfer

In Finder, you can show the Path Bar (View > Show Path Bar). Is it possilbe to select a group of files and drag-and-drop them to another folder there? For example, I may want to copy/move `file1` and `file2` from `~/ivan_/test` to `~/ivan_`:

[image]

Update: Please see my comment in reply to Marc Wilson.

Comment: And what happened when you tried it?

Comment: @MarcWilson Sorry, I've just discovered that copying/moving them in such a way does indeed work. This is a surprise to me because when you drag them to a folder at the main Finder area or to the Previous/Next buttons at the top of the Finder window, the destination folder opens (if you wait for about a second)  and you can decide where exactly to place your files there (assuming you use the Icon view). Do you know whether the same is possible if dragging-and-dropping files to a folder on the Path Bar?